# Integration by substitution, but I cannot see how

Tags: integration, substitution

I am trying to find an indefinite integral. The question suggests that it can be solved with integration by substitution, but I cannot see how. Multiplying out the brackets and integrating gives an eight-order result. Can anyone help here?

$$
\int \left(x+4\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}x+8\right)^6\:dx
$$

Comment: Multiply and divide by $3^6$ (the one in the numerator goes into the exponent expression to cancel out the $\frac 13$). Next,  put $y=x+24$. Now see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it natural to set $u=x/3+8$ ?

Then

$$\int \left(x+4\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}x+8\right)^6\:dx=3\int \left(3u-20\right)u^6\:du$$

which should be easy. (By the way, in all cases integrating a polynomial *is* easy.)

Comment: Yes, thanks very much! The 3 factor confused me for a while, until I realised you're substituting dx = 3 du.